# How do I overwrite a single byte in a binary file using fseek() and fwrite()?

Tags: c++

I am trying to overwrite a single byte in a binary file. I am using `fseek()` to set the stream position indicator to the byte that I want to overwrite. Then I am calling to `fwrite()` with a new byte in that location. Somehow the other bytes in the file are being affected. Heres some code:

```
bool x = 1;
bool y = 0;
bool z = 1;

/* WRITE 101 to file */
FILE *ff = fopen(file, "wb");
fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, ff);
fwrite(&y, sizeof(y), 1, ff);
fwrite(&z, sizeof(y), 1, ff);

fclose(ff);

bool x_r, y_r, z_r;

/* READ from file */
ff = fopen(file, "rb");
fread(&x_r, sizeof(x_r), 1, ff);
fread(&y_r, sizeof(y_r), 1, ff);
fread(&z_r, sizeof(z_r), 1, ff);

fclose(ff);

/* PRINT to standard output */
cout << x_r << y_r << z_r << endl; // OUTPUT: 101

bool overwrite = 1;

/* OVERWRITE */
ff = fopen(file, "wb");

fseek(ff, 1, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&overwrite, sizeof(overwrite),1 , ff);
fclose(ff);


/* READ from file */
ff = fopen(file, "rb");
fread(&x_r, sizeof(x_r), 1, ff);
fread(&y_r, sizeof(y_r), 1, ff);
fread(&z_r, sizeof(z_r), 1, ff);

fclose(ff);

/* PRINT to standard output */
cout << x_r << y_r << z_r << endl; // OUPUT 011; I was expecting 111
```

The above code basically writes three bytes of data to a file. 101. Then I use fseek() to set to reposition the stream indicator to point to the second byte. But calling fwrite() to overwrite the second byte from 0 to 1 is changing the first byte as well. The expected output is 111, but I am getting 011.

Any ideas why this is happening? I tried putc as well, but that didn't work out either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In C++, you are guaranteed that 1 <= sizeof( bool ) <= sizeof( long ).  You should not assume that sizeof( bool ) == 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"r+" mode opens the file for reading and writing, but preserves its contents.

Comment: To be more specific, `"w+"` truncates the file's contents, whilst `"r+"` does not.  When you seek to offset 1 in an empty file and write a byte, that byte gets written, and the bytes before there get zero-filled, so you end up with the two-byte file `00 01`.  And since OP is writing binary data, OP should use the open mode `"r+b"`.

Answer (score 1):

1. seek to the position byte you will update
2. save the rest part of the file (not including the byte being updated) to a buffer or a temp file
3. append one byte with latest value
4. append the content in the buffer or the temp file

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file for *append*, rather than for *write*; i.e.,

```
FILE *ff = fopen(file, "rb+");
```

Write mode truncates the file to zero length as soon as you open it.

Comment: fwrite()'s on files opened in append mode writes(appends) to the end of the file. How do I write in the middle of the file?

Comment: @RakibAnsary have you tried opening in append mode and then using fseek to get it where you want it?

Comment: @Nerdtron Yes I tried that. Using the open mode "ab" doesn't work. Using the open mode "rb+" does work however.

Answer (score 0):

Adams comment is correct.

"wb" completely replaces the file.
Since you start writing at position 1, the function has to put something in position 0, so it puts a NUL byte there.

I agree that you need to use "r+b"

Answer (score 0):

1) use fopen(filename, "r+");
2) seek to the position of the byte or use fread until you find the byte 
3) save the offset of the byte 
3) fseek(fileHandle, offset, SEEK_SET) 
4) fwrite(addr_byte, 1U, 1U, fileHandle)

Answer (score 0):

```
 int fun_write(void *data, int reg_offset, int byte_count) {
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen( "file" , "r+" );
   fseek(fp, reg_offset, SEEK_SET);
   fwrite(data , 1 , byte_count , fp );
   fclose(fp);
}
```